# Square HTML canvas with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, canvas

Let's say I have a HTML canvas with dimensions of 500 x 500. The following CSS code makes a canvas that fills the width and sets the height to the same value, keeping it a square canvas.

```
canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

One would think that changing it to the following CSS code would make the canvas fill the height and set an equivalent width, keeping it square. (this would be used in situations like landscape mode)

```
canvas {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But it doesn't. The canvas reverts to the original 500 x 500. Here is a JFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/0qp5zkgu/ The canvas in the example is 50 x 50 so its easier to see the difference.

Comment: can you please provide a fiddle of this with a proper example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0qp5zkgu/ I changed the canvas size to 50 x 50 so its easier to see the difference.

Comment: Check out the console in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qp5zkgu/1/) as you resize the window... the body height is your issue.

Comment: its literally like 10 lines of code. what would be causing the body height to be wrong?

Comment: You never explicitly set the height of the body (and html). It's not that the body's height is wrong... it's the way that percentage height is handled for _any_ element. It checks the height specified for its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use javascript to set the width and height.

Here's an example::

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main" role="main">
    <canvas id="respondCanvas" width="100" height="100">
        < !-- Provide fallback -->
    </canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

//Get the canvas & context
var c = $('#respondCanvas');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var container = $(c).parent();

//Run function when browser  resize
$(window).resize( respondCanvas );

function respondCanvas(){
    c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
    c.attr('height', $(container).width() ); //set the height to the width to make a square

    //Redraw & reposition content
    var x = c.width();
    var y = c.height();             
    ct.font = "20px Calibri";

    ct.fillStyle = "#DDDDDD"; //black
    ct.fillRect( 0, 0, x, y); //fill the canvas

    var resizeText = "Canvas width: "+c.width()+"px";
    ct.textAlign = "center";
    ct.fillStyle = "#333333"; //white
    ct.fillText(resizeText, (x/2), (y/2) );
}

//Initial call
respondCanvas();
});
```

Fiddle:: http://jsfiddle.net/dp40Lbux/1/

Comment: why would CSS give us one option and not the other ... I didn't want to do it in JS ...

Comment: You have to use javascript because the size of canvas is always in pixels.

Comment: ok, but that's really annoying making a responsive webpage that needs JS to help with the sizing...

Comment: What are you creating that needs canvas?

Comment: a game. it will be a square canvas. there will be other css/html labels and buttons and such around the canvas, which is why I need to have it sized/placed properly.